# How can I learn how jQuery selectors work behind the scenes?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

For example, when we use `$('div span')`, how does jQuery do such a search for us?

Does it search for the `span` element first or the `div`?

It seems that the jQuery official site has no explanation on these things; it just show us what's functions are available through the API.

I want to know how every type jQuery selector is implemented, so I can select the best selector to use.

Do you know where I can get such info?

Comment: The definitive answer is here: https://github.com/jquery/jquery/

Comment: check the jQueru sourcecode http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js

Comment: And in the case of specific selectors, the definitive answer is often here: https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/

Comment: On the other hand if you're choosing your selectors based on which one does the search most efficiently, you're probably doing totally irrelevant micro-optimizing.

Answer (score 7):

Broadly, what you need to know:

1. jQuery reads selectors [from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6028555/901048).
2. [Using an exact ID is fastest](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5029254/901048), followed by using an exact tag name, because they use optimized JavaScript-native methods.
3. Native CSS selectors like `:first-child` are [faster than jQuery selectors](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) like `:first`.

You can also read the [official Sizzle documentation](https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki/Sizzle-Documentation), but it doesn't really discuss optimization techniques.

Answer (score 4):

It searches for the `span` elements first. It parses the selector as:

1. Any element with tagName = span
2. Having an ancestor with tagName = div

For the first part it can use the `getElementsByTagName` method to find all `span` elements, then it has to loop through the ancestors of each to look for `div` elements.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest place to look for would be reading straight from the source. Download the uncompresserd source from jquery site and read from the raw source what it does and in which order.

http://jquery.com/download/

Answer (score 0):

As [@Juhana](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631711/where-i-can-know-how-jquery-selector-works/11631772#comment15404940_11631711) has commented, if you want to know the specific methods jQuery uses to select objects based on its selectors, look at the github repository:

https://github.com/jquery/jquery/

Alternatively, look at the source code available in the uncompressed jQuery download:

http://jquery.com/download/

If you just want to know what different selectors are available for you, jQuery provides a list of them here:

http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

They're parsed from right to left.

See http://csswizardry.com/2011/09/writing-efficient-css-selectors/ and [Why do browsers match CSS selectors from right to left?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797014/css-selectors-parsed-right-to-left-why)