# What is the vanilla javascript version of this jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got this jQuery for processing many radio buttons in a form, but I want to know how I can write it in Vanilla Javascript.

```
const checked_radios = $('input[type="radio"]:checked');
```

Thank you.

I know there are other posts explaining how jQuery works behind the scenes, but the specific cases might be useful not only to me but to others.

Comment: Have a look at this website for future iterations: http://youmightnotneedjquery.com/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I learn how jQuery selectors work behind the scenes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11631711/how-can-i-learn-how-jquery-selectors-work-behind-the-scenes)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll):

```
const checked_radios = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="radio"]:checked');
```